# How to make cell color as fill color which is done by conditional formatting in MS Excel 2010 - VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have researched a lot and found only some scripts. I need assistance in Microsoft Excel 2010.

I have a software generated Excel sheet. It has cell colors which are set using conditional formatting, I want that color to be permanent like fill color of the cell. How this can be achieved in MS Excel 2010.

Comment: It is usually easier to determine if the CF rule's logic is true and then duplicate the CF rule's formatting rather than try to determine the color of a cell's interior that has been changed by a CF rule. Are these CF rule(s) that are based on a formula? Is the only formatting change an interior color fill?

Comment: @Jeeped The software generated Excel sheet is very large in size and consists of around 10k cells and countless hidden cells. Each cell has a unique CF rule logic. The logic is that it gets 3 values from other cells within the sheet and based upon those 3 values it generates the color for the cell individually.

Comment: Actually each row has 15 columns. The CF rule is applied to this column range. Also, there are  such rows 792  such rows. Hence, there are 792 CF rules applied to the sheet. As, I said it is a software generated Excel file.

My question is, is it possible to make conditional formatted color rules for each cell to make them permanent. Is there any in built tool or method in MS Excel 2010 to do so?

Comment: Why do you need to replace the CF coloring with fixed colors?

Comment: In Excel you can use `cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` to find the CF color, and set the `cell.Interior.Color` to that value, then remove all the CF.

Comment: @TimWilliams Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel 2010+ you can loop over the cells, use `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` to find the CF color, and set the `Interior.Color` to that value, then remove all the CF.

```
Sub CopyCfFills()

    Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    'Get all cells with CF: `On Error Resume Next` ignores error if no cells
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllFormatConditions)
    On Error GoTo 0

    '...or a specific range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("AO7:AY43")

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No CF on this sheet!"
    Else
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            c.Interior.Color = c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
            c.FormatConditions.Delete
        Next c
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I want that to be done by just using MS Excel.

Comment: That is using macro code in Excel.  There's no built-in way to do it.

Comment: How do I select multiple rows of Excel. I want to perform your above code for AO7: AY7 to AO43: AY43.

Answer (score 0):

Use this vba sub which will make cell colors, which will match cell N3. You can change condition like, greater than, less that etc.

```
Private Sub cmdSelectValues_Click()
Dim MyInput<br>

MyInput = Range("N3").Value
  Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
  Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
      Formula1:="=" & MyInput
  Cells.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

  With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
      .Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
  End With

End Sub
```

Output of code.
[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I want that to be done by just using MS Excel.

Comment: Yes it is only using excel. Just used vba. Do you mean by only excel builtin formulas?

Comment: Yes, and how do I select multiple rows and columns as range?

Comment: It will select all value within given condition. For more advance you need customize code. Can you share sample workbook?